# How can I show $| \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik}|$ is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I know that we can write

$ \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik} = \frac{e^{i(n+1)} -1}{e^i - 1}$

But I am unsure how to proceed with showing there's some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \space \text{it holds that} \space \|\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik} \| \leq M $

Comment: You have an explicit formula for the sum; just show it's bounded.

Comment: $|e^{i(n+1)} |\leq 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're done, since $$\|e^{i(n+1)}-1\|\leq 2,$$
because $e^{i(n+1)}$ is a complex number on the unit circle, and $\frac{1}{e^i-1}$ has a constant modulus.

That gives:
$$ \left\|\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{ik}\right\|\leq \frac{1}{\sin\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks jack, could I please confirm some details?

When you say $\| e^{i(n+1)} - 1 \| \leq 2$ 
in taking the modulus of that expression, I believe the output is some real number? If so, how would you express this?

Additionally, I am unsure how you got the expression  $\sin \frac{1}{2}$ in the denominator, would you care to explain that?

Comment: @piman314: just try to figure out where $e^i$ is in the unit circle to deduce the value of $\|e^i-1\|$, namely $2\sin\frac{1}{2}$.